# Is there a bug in new Eclipse (2020-06) editor?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've just downloaded the new Eclipse

```
Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)
Build id: 20200615-1200
```

I am using it in fullscreen mode on Mac Catalina 10.15.5

If I switch to another screen and come back to Eclipse, the editor might have a bug? It get's a bit 'out of control' and I have to close the tab and reopen it to fix it:

[image: bug in eclipse editor]

Do you also have such problems, out there?

Comment: What does 'out of control' mean? What is happening? What is the circled area supposed to show?

Comment: I think it's the smaller repeated line numbers, which I haven't seen. If this is consistently reproducible, @mrbela, it should be reported as a bug in Bugzilla.

Comment: @greg-449: It seems to be a "graphic bug". The circled area shows a copy of the "lines view". If I then add new lines, the circled area is updated, but the 'general lines view' wohn't be updated any more... Very strange.

Comment: @nitind: It's 99,9% chance a bug. As far as I know how to reproduce it, I am going to report it via Bugzilla.

Comment: Yes, i have same problem, i can not find solution.